# React Native - Fetch localhost = Network request failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am new to react native and I have a asp.net API running on LocalHost and I trying to fetch it but I just get:

> "Network request failed".

I have tried as people suggested and using my IP address and I still got the same error. I have also tried using ngrok but I also couldn't get that working. I tried the same link with Postman and everything works fine its just with react native that is giving me errors. I have also tried the 10.0.2.2+port number and still getting the error.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://localhost:44384/api/task')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => setData(json))
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);
```

Comment: Did you try with your local IP?

Comment: @J.Rayhan I did